# Identifying extremes in pandas timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, math, data-science

I'm looking for a way to identify the local extremes in a pandas timeseries.

A MWE would be

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

sin_list = []
for i in range(200):
    sin_list.append(math.sin(i / 10) + i / 100)

idx = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=200, freq='H')

ts = pd.Series(sin_list, index=idx)

ts.plot(style='.')
plt.show()
```

and the red lines would mark the timestamps which I want to identify. Note that there are, of course, finite steps in this series.

A possible solution could be to fit a curve to it, derive it and then identify the exact place where the gradient is 0. This does seem like a big effort to program myself, and I assume such an implementation exists somewhere.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a solution for the problem based on the `.diff()` module. The crucial attribute here is the `p` factor of the get_percentile function. Since the finite number of values means that the gradient will not attain value 0, the solution space must be blurred a bit. This means, the less values there are, the higher the `p` factor must be. In my solution 0.05 proved to be sufficient to identify the extremes, but small enough to locate the extremes with reasonable accuracy.

[image]

This is the code:

```
import copy
import math

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def get_percentile(data: list, p: float):
    _data = copy.copy(data)
    _data.sort()
    result = _data[math.floor(len(_data) * p) - 1]
    return result


sin_list = []
for i in range(200):
    sin_list.append(math.sin(i / 10) + i / 100)

idx = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=200, freq='H')

ts = pd.Series(sin_list, index=idx)

gradient_ts = abs(ts.diff())

percentile = get_percentile(gradient_ts.values, p=0.05)

binary_ts = gradient_ts.where(gradient_ts > percentile, 1).where(gradient_ts < percentile, 0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
binary_ts.plot(drawstyle="steps", ax=ax)
ax.fill_between(binary_ts.index, binary_ts, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5, step='pre')

ts.plot(secondary_y=True, style='.')

plt.show()
```